# Testing StateFlow not collect all states

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-hilt

I tried to test StateFlows states. But I cannot get all states. Just last state what I getting.
Here's my view model:

```
@HiltViewModel
class ExerciseViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val exerciseRepository: BaseRepository,
    private val exerciseMapper: ExerciseMapper
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _data = MutableStateFlow(Exercise())
    val data: StateFlow<Exercise> = _data.asStateFlow()
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow<ExerciseViewState?>(null)
    val state: StateFlow<ExerciseViewState?> = _state.asStateFlow()

    fun loadExercise(id: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _state.value = ExerciseViewState.Loading
            try {
                val result = exerciseRepository.getExercise(id)
                _data.value = exerciseMapper.map(result)
                _state.value = ExerciseViewState.Data
                _state.value = ExerciseViewState.Error
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _state.value = ExerciseViewState.Error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's what I am try to test:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class ExerciseViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    var rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
    val mainDispatcherRule = MainDispatcherRule()

    private var exerciseRepository = FakeExerciseRepository()
    private var exerciseMapper = ExerciseMapper()
    lateinit var viewModel: ExerciseViewModel

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
        viewModel = ExerciseViewModel(
            exerciseRepository = exerciseRepository,
            exerciseMapper = exerciseMapper
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun test() = runTest {
        val stateList = mutableListOf<ExerciseViewState?>()
        val job = launch {
            viewModel.state.toList(stateList)
        }
        viewModel.loadExercise(id = 1)
        advanceUntilIdle()
        assertContains(stateList, ExerciseViewState.Loading)
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

stateList returns only last state ([ExerciseViewState.Error])
I wanna reach all the values what states have. ([Loading,Data,Error])
How can I do this ?

Comment: Is `exerciseRepository.getExercise()` a suspending function? If not, the collector in the test never gets a chance to collect the `Loading` value before the `Data` value replaces it in the `StateFlow`. `StateFlow` is conflated by default, so you will only see intermediate states when there are suspensions in the right places

Comment: Yes, it is a suspend function. @Joffrey

Comment: So I see 2 possible problems: 1) the `launch` in the test function doesn't necessarily reach `toList` before you run `loadExercise`, and 2) maybe `exerciseRepository.getExercise()` is suspending but doesn't *actually* suspend during the test (depending on the implementation)

Comment: You could fix problem 1 by making the `launch` run in `Dispatcher.Unconfined`, and problem 2 by properly mocking the repository and controlling when it suspends (which IMO would be a better test). Meaning: a) call `loadExercise`, b) verify loading state, c) use your mock to let go of the suspension, d) verify data state

Comment: Can u explain the "Meaning" section with code ? I may have tried what you said.

Comment: I tried run launch in```Dispatcher.Unconfined```. This add to stateList first value -> null. Final result is [null,Error]

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to adapt it to your use case in a succinct way, but here is an example mock that I used, which could inspire a mock for your ExerciseRepository: https://github.com/joffrey-bion/krossbow/blob/main/krossbow-websocket-test/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/hildan/krossbow/websocket/test/WebSocketClientMocks.kt. And then usage could look like this: https://github.com/joffrey-bion/krossbow/blob/eb5f56a98da2d9a5506495bd5136417a8ad54a0d/krossbow-websocket-core/src/commonTest/kotlin/org/hildan/krossbow/websocket/reconnection/ReconnectingWebSocketClientTest.kt#L19-L32

Comment: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/3339 this topic solves my problem thanks for your support! @Joffrey